# How to Adjust Camber on a 1999 Chevy Suburban

Tags: chevrolet, suburban, lift-kit

I have a C1500 (2wd, 1/2 ton frame) 1999 Suburban with 4 in spindles installed, but now the camber is much to negative and it's going to cause wear on my tires, and I can't seem to adjust the camber on this car.

What would be the recommended way to correct the camber?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the upper control arms are two eccentric bolts for adjusting caster and camber.

[image]

In this image the knockouts for camber/caster adjustment haven't been removed.

[image]

And would need to be either cut out or use a special tool made by OTC.

[image]

You need a camber gauge and plates or an alignment machine to set camber.

If the camber on the bolts are maxed you can use offset balljoints.

[image]

Comment: I have to say that I didn't think it was possible.  Glad I didn't answer and stuck to motorcycles.   +1

Comment: Yup, there actually were already cam bolts and the knock outs were removed, it just wasn't adjusted all the way out, which means the mechanic who said you couldn't align this car was just lazy. But camber is perfect and it's all good to go, thanks a ton!

Comment: @BrianLeishman good to hear